# Return result from method to another method

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have got this method which I would like to return

```
public void najdi_pojistovnu()
    {
        string sqlcom = "SELECT id FROM pojist WHERE name LIKE '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (sqlcom,spojeni);
        spojeni.Open();
        int result= Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        spojeni.Close();

        return result;

    }
```

And I would like to call the result from another method like this:

```
  najdi_pojistovnu();
```

But I gex this ex: Since (path).najdi_poistovnu() return void a return keyword must not be followed by an objext expression

Would you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are returning `result` which is of `int` type thus change function signature

Change

```
public void najdi_pojistovnu()
```

to

```
public int najdi_pojistovnu()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int najdi_pojistovnu()
    {
        string sqlcom = "SELECT id FROM pojist WHERE name LIKE '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (sqlcom,spojeni);
        spojeni.Open();
        int result= Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        spojeni.Close();

        return result;

    }
```

Or

```
public void najdi_pojistovnu(out int result)
    {
        string sqlcom = "SELECT id FROM pojist WHERE name LIKE '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (sqlcom,spojeni);
        spojeni.Open();
        result= Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        spojeni.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to return int value in void method. Correct syntax is:

```
public int najdi_pojistovnu()
{
    string sqlcom = "SELECT id FROM pojist WHERE name LIKE '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (sqlcom,spojeni);
    spojeni.Open();
    int result= Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
    spojeni.Close();

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> gex this ex: Since (path).najdi_poistovnu() return void a return keyword must not be followed by an objext expression

your function signature says that this method will not return anything.  whereas you are trying to return an int (result) from your function.

Now, if you want to return integer you should change your definition like this

```
 public int najdi_pojistovnu()
```

> And I would like to call the result from another method like this: najdi_pojistovnu();

you can call it like this

```
int result = najdi_pojistovnu();
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)

> Methods are declared in a class or struct by specifying the access
>   level such as public or private, optional modifiers such as abstract
>   or sealed, the return value, the name of the method, and any method
>   parameters. These parts together are the signature of the method.